# Simpler way to alias instance variables to other instance variables in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators, declaration

Given the below **struct** in Swift, is there a more concise way to alias the instance variables `x`, `y`, and `z` to the properties of the three-tuple, `_v`?

Note: I realize that, of course, I could just declare these instance variables as Doubles and not need the tuple. However, the reason I'm doing it this way is so I can set three variables with a single-line statement like you will see in the `init` method and the below sample code.

Sample code with desired output of "1.0" "4.0":

```
var myVector = Vector3([1.0,2.0,3.0])
let x = myVector.x
print(x)
myVector.v = (4.0,5.0,6.0)
print(x)
```

The class:

```
struct Vector3 {

    typealias V3 = (x:Double,y:Double,z:Double)

    var v:V3 = (x:0.0,y:0.0,z:0.0)

    var x:Double {
        get {
            return v.x
        }
        set(x) {
            v.x = x
        }
    }

    var y:Double {
        get {
            return v.y
        }
        set(y) {
            v.y = y
        }
    }

    var z:Double {
        get {
            return v.z
        }
        set(z) {
            v.z = z
        }
    }

    init(_ args:AnyObject...) {
        if(args[0].isKindOfClass(NSArray)) {
            v = (args[0][0].doubleValue,args[0][1].doubleValue,args[0][2].doubleValue)
        }
        else if(args.count == 3){
            v = (args[0].doubleValue,args[1].doubleValue,args[2].doubleValue)
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is:

```
struct Vector3 {

    typealias V3 = (x:Double,y:Double,z:Double)

    var v:V3 = (x:0.0,y:0.0,z:0.0)

    alias x = v.x
    alias y = v.y
    alias z = v.z

    init(_ args:AnyObject...) {
        if(args[0].isKindOfClass(NSArray)) {
            v = (args[0][0].doubleValue,args[0][1].doubleValue,args[0][2].doubleValue)
        }
        else if(args.count == 3){
            v = (args[0].doubleValue,args[1].doubleValue,args[2].doubleValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that doesn't work. But is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

### Just do the opposite!

> I realize that, of course, I could just declare these instance variables as Doubles and not need the tuple. However, the reason I'm doing it this way is so I can set three variables with a single-line statement like you will see in the init method and the below sample code.

If this is the reason then just do the opposite

```
struct Vector3 {

    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var z: Double

    var coordinates: (Double, Double, Double) {
        set { (x, y, z) = newValue }
        get { return (x, y, z) }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var vector = Vector3(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)
vector.x = 4
vector.coordinates // (4, 2, 3)
```

### Final note

Your initializer could be improved in several ways.

1. Stop using NSArray, you are using Swift not Objective-C
2. Stop using `isKindOfClass`, use `as?` to perform a conditional cast
3. You have faith the objects inside the first array/s will have a `doubleValue` property. So I could easily crash your `init` passing something different right?

### Now my question

What's wrong with the memberwise struct initializer?

It is automatically generated when you don't explicitly define an initializer for  a struct, like in my previous code snipped.

Are you sure you want to define an initializer that literally accept any sort of objects an will crash with 99.99% of the combinations of values someone can pass to it?